# Eslint rules for combined Typescript & Javascript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

We have a project that is written in Typescript, under the `src` folder, but the integration tests (using mocha & chai) in the `test` folder are written in ES6 Javascript. This is causing an error to be reported in VSCode:

> Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
> The file does not match your project config: test/endpoints/promotions.js.
> The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.

It is not a breaking error, but it would be nice to have the tests linted appropriately.

Is there any way to set up eslint so that it applies Typescript rules in the `src` folder and basic Javascript rules in the `test`?

BTW We appreciate that should probably update the integration tests to be in Typescript, but we don't currently have that time luxury.

Comment: Have you looked at overrides? https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ignore `test/*` in your `.eslintignore` file